# GNU sort and git blame

Tags: unix, git, sorting, gnu, cut

Today I thought I was doing a simple operation:

```
git blame file | sort -k 3
```

To get all the lines of `file` sorted by the date on which they were last changed.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be sorting it correctly.  It *does* work if I do the following:

```
git blame file | cut -c 20- | sort
```

Which just hacks the first part of the line off and then does the sort.  The success of this command indicates to me that `sort` *can* in fact do the operation I was trying.  Why didn't  it work?

Here's an example line from the output of `git blame file`:

```
35d8e9eb (username 2007-01-17 03:58:04 +0000 155) Some text on line 155
```

Edit:  Using any reasonable number besides `3` in the original command line seems to work fine - I can sort by the hash (field 1), the username (field 2), the time of day (field 4), or the line number (field 6), but the date (field 3) doesn't work - I can't identify at all what order it actually ends up in...

Edit 2:  I've made a sanitized input file that shows the same problem.  Here's `cleaned.txt`:

```
cb7bb041 (eeeeeee  2010-12-14 19:41:18 +0000  42)
35d8e9eb (cccccccc 2007-01-17 03:58:04 +0000 135)
d7377fa9 (hhhhhhhh 2010-01-30 04:26:28 +0000 178)
```

And the output from `sort -k 3 cleaned.txt`:

```
$ sort -k 3 cleaned.txt 
cb7bb041 (eeeeeee  2010-12-14 19:41:18 +0000  42)
35d8e9eb (cccccccc 2007-01-17 03:58:04 +0000 135)
d7377fa9 (hhhhhhhh 2010-01-30 04:26:28 +0000 178)
```

As you can see the sorting on the date field didn't appear to take place at all.  Here's the output from `cut -c 20- cleaned.txt | sort`:

```
$ cut -c 20- cleaned.txt | sort
2007-01-17 03:58:04 +0000 135)
2010-01-30 04:26:28 +0000 178)
2010-12-14 19:41:18 +0000  42)
```

Sorting on dates in that case works fine! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured it out. The shorter username `eeeeeee` means there's an extra space before the date field.  Since the field separator for `sort` is a non-blank to blank transition, the date field for the line with the shorter username has that space as part of the key field, and gets sorted first.  Simple fix:

```
git blame file | sort -b -k 3
```

Comment: You also have to watch out for author names that have different numbers of spaces in them. Your examples all have single-word author names (`eeeeeee`, `cccccccc`, and `hhhhhhhh`), but real names will often vary (e.g. git.git has author names with as few as one and up to five space separated “words”). Using `-e` might help; the email addresses it shows are much less likely to have any spaces.

Comment: @Chris - good point.  This was just a one-off that confused me, so I'm not worried about it in general, but that's good to remember if I were to script this up.